# Use Auto Layout to create UITableView with multiple different custom cells have almost the same subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

**My idea for this App:** Create a list of Users with extra info based job title.

**My coding:**

To show the list, I use UITableView with dynamic table view cell height and Auto Layout. Because all cells have almost the same SubViews (example: Avatar, Full Name, Description), I want to use only 1 custom UITableViewCell to show user info.

This is image for CustomCell.xib: [Custom Cell + Extra Info Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbudy.png)

Extra Info is UIView and I will replace it with right extra info for each job type (Example: UIImageView for Photographer, UITextField to show list of books for Author, etc).

When I load user data from Database or API, I only assign each row for CustomCell class with code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(customCellIdentifier) as! CustomCell

    cell.userData = allUserData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    return cell
}
```

And this is the code of CustomCell class (I removed the code to set up avatar, full name, description to make post shorter):

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var userData: NSDictionary! {
        didSet {
            updateContent()
        }
    }

    function updateContent() {
        if let userType = userData["job_type"] as? String {
            if (userType == "Photographer") {
                // I think I was wrong with this code
                let photographerContentView = PhotographerView()
                photographerContentView.mainImage = UIImage(name: userData["image"] as String)
                self.extraInfoView = photographerContentView
            } else {
                // I have a lot job types need to check
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PhotographerView is custom UIView and I will load it from a xib file with setup Auto Layout

```
class PhotographerView: UIView {
@IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImage!
var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "PhotographerView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}
}
```

**The Problem:**

- I can't draw PhotographerContentView with new data with Auto Layout and assign it to extraInfoView
- I know that I can complete my app by creating a new custom UITableViewCell for each user job type like [Dynamic Table View Cell Height and Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout). But if I do like that, I will have to change all custom xib files when I need to add more same subviews like Address, Phone Number, etc in future.
- I know that UIView has no intrinsic content size at Auto Layout Guide from Apple Docs but I need the way to render custom view with Auto Layout and add it to parent view with full width of screen (maybe I need to add constraints programmatically).

What is the best solution for my issue? And can you give me some example code for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off creating one custom cell type per unique layout. Otherwise, you'll be taking an unnecessary performance hit every time you render a cell. This line in particular is going to be relatively expensive, since you'll be reloading the view from the XIB every time:

```
let photographerContentView = PhotographerView()
```

You could place the common code/layout in an "abstract" base class and simply have your concrete cell types extend this type. For example, you would have a base `JobCell` class that `PhotographerCell`, etc. would extend. That way, you'll get much better value out of cell reuse, and your code will probably be simpler.

As I've mentioned [elsewhere](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/), you could certainly use MarkupKit to help simplify your layout tasks. Your `PhotographerView` class could be implemented exactly as you have written, except that instead of loading the view from a XIB, you'd load it from a markup document using the `viewWithName:owner:root:` method of `LMViewBuilder`. With MarkupKit, you declare the layout of your cell using (optionally nested) layout views, rather than by manually applying constraints as you would in a XIB file. For example:

https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-table-view-cells-in-markup-1

For more information about MarkupKit, see the [project site](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit) on GitHub.